# Getting a lot of '/_' errors from webmaster tools

Tags: seo, google-search-console, 404

I'm using a WordPress site and I thought I got all the kinks out of it. For some reason Webmaster Tools is crawling my website and showing a lot of 404 errors which are from `/_` like additional pages that I've never created. I just can't figure out what is creating these for Google crawlers and then displaying a 404.

My robots.txt is [here](http://www.redcherryshrimp.net/robots.txt).

My sitemap (created by the Yoast plugin) is [here](http://www.redcherryshrimp.net/sitemap_index.xml).

I have Yoast and Jetpack plugins installed. What could be causing these links to appear

Comment: Have you checked where those pages are being linked from? (Click on the page name on the list under "Health > Crawl errors", then open the "Linked from" tab on the popup.)

Comment: @llmari "Linked from" and "in Sitemaps" show no data in any of the 404 errors. Now that i look at all the (256) 404 errors, they are all attachments or uploads (ie: pictures).

Comment: That's strange. [This similar question](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/26364/404-errors-showing-in-google-webmaster-tools) and [this answer](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/20169/) to another related question suggest that these URLs might once have been linked from somewhere, and perhaps might have actually worked, and Google now keeps trying to recrawl them because it thinks there used to be something there. Sending a "410 Gone" response or redirecting them to a working URL might help, as might using the URL removal tool on Webmaster Tools.

Comment: You got an answer to your question that should help you, but your situation is so specific that this question is unlikely to help anybody else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is your blue 'want to advertise' banner at the top of every page.

It is linking to a 404 on every page as the link is defined as a relative URL linking to the page with an under score and hash tag appended.

```
<a href="_#"
```

So the banner links to a 404 page on every page it appears on.

e.g

on http://www.redcherryshrimp.net/ the banner links to http://www.redcherryshrimp.net/_

This is the view of the offending link in the source code:

```
 <div class="textwidget"><a href="_#"> <img src="http://www.RedCherryShrimp.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/728x90-Top-Banner-Ad.png"></img></a></div>
```

Comment: wow i feel stupid now... I was testing out ad banners and must of been a Monday error.